# Asking for all cpus on a node and minimum number of cpus

Tags: slurm, hpc

Is it possible to ask for all cpus on a node while specifying only nodes which have a number of cores greater than some number?

Alternatively, is it possible to make `--cpu-per-task` vary based on the `--constraint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set

```
#SBATCH --mincpus=<min number of CPUs>
#SBATCH --exclusive
```

Slurm will then allocated for your job the first entire node becoming free, that has enough CPUs.